# $_SESSION variable in php (page to page)

Tags: php, html

Whenever I go to a page i.e. login page or any other page, I want to save the name of the page in a `$_SESSION` variable.

login page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['page'] = 'login.htm';    
?>
```

It works only for the login page and doesnt overwrite in other pages for e.g. home page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['page'] = "home.htm"; 
?>
```

I need the sesssion variable 'page' to hold the last page I was, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`? This will give you the previous page in PHP, without having to add anything to sessions.

Comment: am making like an app so i need to know it for REDIRECTION purpose

Comment: Note that HTTP_REFERER will not work properly when user refreshes page

Comment: You can still use this for redirection purposes. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: sorry am new on web design, how would the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] work like in the case of my example ..

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] holds the page the user came from, so assuming the user was at "home.htm" and clicked a link to go to "login.htm", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "home.htm

Answer (score 1):

when you navigate to a new page first retrive the saved "back" variable (and use it in a back link/breadcrumbs or something), and then overwrite the sessions "back" variable with the curent page, to have it ready for the next move =)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is default "back" functionality you should let the browser handle it.

If what you want is something to be used as a breadcrumb following some internal order (or path in a tree) my advice is to let each page "know" the path that leads to it.

If you really need to know from what page the user came from save it to a previous variable before you write over the current variable.

```
// Make sure user didnt just refresh the page
if ($_SESSION["current"] !== "currentPage.php") {
  $_SESSION["previous"] = $_SESSION["current"];
  $_SESSION["current"] = "currentPage.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using different keys.. `'page'` and `'back'`.